# object popping itself from stack

Tags: c++, containers

example code:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::stack<A>* pStack){
        this->pStack = pStack;
    }

    void popMe(){
        pStack->pop();
    }
protected:
    std::stack<A>* pStack;
};

int main()
{
    std::stack<A> s;
    s.push(A(&s));
    s.top().popMe();
    return 0;
}
```

Stack of objects(or other container with pop-like method), each object has pointer to stack so it can pop itself(or any other object in case of other type of container). My questions is:

1. is object deleted when its popped from stack?
2. is it safe to call popMe method
3. yes, i know this code is weird and hard to understand/debug. any better ideas how to manage communication between objects on stack and stack (or object containing this stack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[1] An object on a stack is destructed always!

[2] The method is not safe. What if the object is not the current top one.

[3] You may extend the std::stack adapter and notify the object being removed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

template <typename T>
class Stack
{
    private:
    typedef std::stack<T> stack_type;

    public:
    typedef typename stack_type::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename stack_type::reference reference;
    typedef typename stack_type::const_reference const_reference;
    typedef typename stack_type::size_type size_type;
    typedef typename stack_type::container_type container_type;

    public:
    explicit Stack(const container_type& container = container_type())
    : m_stack(container)
    {}

    bool empty() const { return m_stack.empty(); }
    size_type size() const { return m_stack.size(); }
    reference top() { return m_stack.top(); }
    const_reference top() const { return m_stack.top(); }
    void push(const value_type& x) { m_stack.push(x); }
    void push(value_type&& x) { m_stack.push(std::move(x)); }

    template<typename... Args>
    void emplace(_Args&&... args) {
        m_stack.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void pop() {
        top().stack_pop_event(*this);
        m_stack.pop();
    }

    void swap(Stack& other) {
        m_stack.swap(other.m_stack);
    }

    private:
    stack_type m_stack;
};

class A
{
    public:
    void stack_pop_event(const::Stack<A>&){
        std::cout << "Pop\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Stack<A> s;
    s.push(A());
    s.pop();
    return 0;
}
```

(C++11)

Comment: thanks for suggestion, it's cool if you compare to my code example, but i'm afraid i oversimplified it. my point is to call method from top object deciding whether pop itsfelf or not. i know there's possibility other object call popMe but that's the point of stack to have access to top element only (even if there's workaround as @Pavel Davydov mentioned).

Comment: well, i reconsidered your code and it's actually easy to modify to fit my needs, thanks again. i'll mark it as answer

Answer (score 1):

1 - Object's destructor will be called.

2 - You don't check if pointer is zero. Also, imagine the following code:

```
std::stack<A> s;
s.push(A(&s));
auto& head = s.top();
s.push(A(&s));
// ...
head.popMe(); //pops another element
```

3 - See boost::intrusive containers. It has [unlink hooks](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/intrusive/auto_unlink_hooks.html).

Comment: ad2 good point with this code on the other hand using such reference might be unsafe anyway.

Comment: @ignorant yes, it can, cause one can pop it while you use a reference. This can be fixed with a shared pointer however. You have to copy a shared pointer this way, do not hold a reference.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is object deleted when its popped from stack?

Yes. But it will be the copy of one you pushed in.

1. Is it safe to call popMe method

Yes

You can find stack documentation here
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/push/

```
void push (const value_type& val);
```

Inserts a new element at the top of the stack, above its current top element. The content of this new element is initialized to a copy of val.

So std::stack stores only copies. If you want it to be responsible for deallocating original elements you should use

```
std::stack<std::shared_ptr<A>>
```

Comment: `std::stack::pop` will absolutely delete the object.

Answer (score 0):

1. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/pop/
2. there is no check against the nullptr, so once pStack points to null you try to dereference the NULL ptr triggering undefined behaviour.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what he's trying to do. Not wrapping stack, but having a stack item pop itself.

Comment: hm, thx for pointing out - need to read more carefully - modifying as the answer is rather confusing.. (+1 for the remark)

Comment: with this code not:  std::stack<A> s; s.push(A(&s)); s.top().popMe();  but shouldn't it be just a good practice to prevent any potential class missuses?